# Android: how to handle network connectivity like play store app

Tags: android, webview

**I HAVE RESOLVED THIS NOW**

*I want to handle network connectivity like the play store app.*

I have created a webview and want to load a URL say www.bing.com

If network connection is available Then
   Load URL
Else
   Load Custom URL with Button.
End

1. If there is no connectivity on pressing this button i want to try and load the URL again ? In other words i want to call this activity again after user has connectivity. How do i do that ?

   Below is my code :

   ```
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager; 
    import android.net.NetworkInfo; 
    import android.os.Bundle; 
    import android.app.Activity; 
    import android.view.Menu; 
    import android.view.MenuItem; 
    import android.webkit.WebView; 
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient; 
    import android.widget.Toast; 
    import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils; 
    import android.annotation.TargetApi; 
    import android.content.Context; 
    import android.os.Build;


   public class WebActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);


       if(isNetworkStatusAvailable (getApplicationContext())) {

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
           myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.bing.com");

           myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

               @Override
               public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                       String description, String failingUrl) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet Connection Unavailable Or " + description , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                   Intent errorIntent = new Intent(WebActivity.this, NetworkErrorActivity.class);
                   startActivity(errorIntent); 
                   finish();

                   super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
               }
            });

       } else {

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet Connection Unavailable.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   Intent errorIntent = new Intent(this, NetworkErrorActivity.class);
                   startActivity(errorIntent); 
                   finish();


        }

       // Show the Up button in the action bar.
       setupActionBar();
   }

   public static boolean isNetworkStatusAvailable (Context context) {
       ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       if (connectivityManager != null) 
       {
           NetworkInfo netInfos = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
           if(netInfos != null)
           if(netInfos.isConnected()) 
               return true;
       }
       return false;
   }

   }
   ```

Comment: Just saying, I don't think play store app on android is using web view. For your question, possible way to do that is when network isn't available, replace your web view with some other view (like relative layout ) which contains a retry button.

Comment: i was trying your solution from yesterday but i somehow couldn't work with a button from a webview.

I have now solved this using the following method - 
i replaced the code inside else with

Intent errorIntent = new Intent(this, NetworkErrorActivity.class);
startActivity(errorIntent); 

In my new activity i call my previous activity again by pressing a button. Finally it works !!

Comment: What do you mean by "call my previous activity again"? If you are trying to start a new activity instead of returning to your previous activity, that will mess up your back stack.

Comment: i have edited my code now. i am in my mainActivity, i clicked a button that sends me to webActivity. what i needed was when the user does not have network connectivity, instead of webActivity redirect him to errorActivity that says no network available and show him a retry button. On clicking this retry button, if network is available then send him back to webActivity. i have used finish(); to avoid backstack. Do you think this would pose a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use fragments. onCreate check for internet connectivity and if available load the fragment with webview else load fragment with button. in button OnClick again check for internet availability , on response you can replace the fragment with webView.

Comment: I am still learning how to use fragments but i think your solution works perfectly, because presently instead of two fragments i am using two activities. I just had some problem with the button. Now it works fine. I will try using fragments next.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Can you throw some light on this? blog or article something?